# IRF with I(1) variables? VECM needed?

Tags: r, time-series, model, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

Here is a question related to IRF, impulse response functions, in the [vars package](http://www.pfaffikus.de/files/rpack/vars/vars.pdf).

My data has following attributes: I do have two log-transformed variables that are tested as **I(1)**. I.e. the two variables are stationary after first differencing and not stationary at level, allowing for "constant and trend". The I(1) variables are found to be cointegrated.

- What do I have to consider when drawing an impulse response function
  (`irf()`)?
- Can I use my variables at level (which are not stationary) or do I have to use the first-differenced data?
- In case: When do I have to use a VECM?

Comment: *VECM* stands for *vector error correction model*, so you do not need to repeat *model* after *VECM*.

Comment: Okay. Will keep it in mind. Let me assure on the procedure: Case 1: Variables are both I(1) and cointegrated: Estimate IRF with VECM. Case 2: Variables are both I(1) but not cointegrated: Estimate IRF with first-differenced variables. Correct?

Comment: I think that's right.